# What is the sql query for this?

Tags: sql, h2

```
Id  Project_Id       Activity_Time        Username
1      100        2008-01-01 11:12:13         A
2      100        2008-01-01 00:00:00         B
3      500        2008-02-01 00:00:00         C
4      300        2008-02-03 00:00:00         D
5      500        2008-03-03 11:11:11         A
6      300        2008-04-04 00:00:00         D
7      500        2008-05-05 00:00:00         C
8      200        2008-06-06 00:00:00         D
9      100        2009-01-01 11:12:13         A
10     300        2010-01-01 01:02:03         A
```

What is the sql query to select **Project_Id** based on following input :

1. for the given username
2. order by Activity_Time - latest first
3. distinct Project_Id
4. only 10 rows

I tried few queries nothing worked, so seeking help here.
Currently H2 database is used but it would change over a period.

[Update] This is a true project requirement, not a home work, am a newbie, please don't make fun, am learning the stuffs.

Comment: What is your database management system?

Comment: A sample of what you expect to see would be better than your description of what you want.

Comment: Looks suspiciously like homework.

Comment: Hoi! True enough. But still... :-)

Comment: Show us what you tried, and why it didn't work, you will learn more from your own mistakes than you will by us just giving you a solution.

Comment: The flavour of DBMS does matter when it come the syntax for limiting by rowcount.

Comment: Actually the information is there. He mentioned "H2". Didn't realize this until rereading.

Comment: aren't the tags "sql" and "h2" mutually exclusive? I thought h2 was a way to access a database using only java and with no sql. **Hey OP, do you want a SQL select statement or the h2 java code?**

Comment: Guys, this is not a homework, this true project requirement. Am looking for SQL statement.

Comment: @Frank Kalis - yep I missed that too.  Mind you, OP says "it would change over a period."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be a good start if not completely working ...

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    project_ID, max(activity_time) as activity_time
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    username = usernameVariable
GROUP BY 
    project_id
ORDER BY 
    activity_time DESC
```

Comment: Following exception thrown when the above query is executed :

Order by expression ACTIVITY_TIME must be in the result list in this case; SQL statement:

Comment: The DISTINCT is now not needed.